# Based on the following distribution can I say I have two seasons in my data from 1-26 and 26-52?

Tags: regression, arima, seasonality

I have a dataset for one year of weekly sales revenue of sale of milk for each farmer, I'm trying to figure out seasonality trend in my data, based on my data, can I say I have two seasons in my dataset the one with the upward trend and the other with the downward trend?
[image]

Comment: The milk market must have yearly seasonality, i.e. one season per year, because of the effect the different seasons of the year on cows and on demand for milk. The "seasons" you identify should not be called seasons in the statistical sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to rely purely on the data, there's a limit to what you can conclude with one year of measurements.

But wouldn't you be surprised if there was no seasonality? Your expectation was probably that there would be some seasonality - and this data is consistent with that. To put it in Bayesian terms, your prior should dominate because your data are limited.